# echo "eval `dircolors ${dircolorsdb}`" >> ~/.zshrc didn't work as I expected

Tags: command-line, bash, echo

I want to insert

```
eval `dircolors $HOME/.dir_colors/dircolors.256dark`
```

in my  `~/.zshrc`

I assigned a variable:

```
dircolorsdb=$HOME/.dir_colors/dircolors.256dark
```

I expect double quotes to result in an expansion:

```
echo "eval `dircolors ${dircolorsdb}`" >> ~/.zshrc
```

expands to

```
eval LS_COLORS='no=00;38;5;244:rs=0:di=00;38;5;33:ln=00;38;5;37:mh=00:pi=48;5;230;38;5;136;01:so=48;5;230;38;5;136;01:do=48;5;230;38;5;136;01:bd=48;5;230;38;5;244;01:cd=48;5;230;38;5;244;01:or=48;5;235;38;5;160:su=48;5;160;38;5;230:sg=48;5;136;38;5;230:ca=30;41:tw=48;5;64;38;5;230:ow=48;5;235;38;5;33:st=48;5;33;38;5;230:ex=00;38;5;64:*.tar=00;38;5;61:*.tgz=00;38;5;61:*.arj=00;38;5;61:*.taz=00;38;5;61:*.lzh=00;38;5;61:*.lzma=00;38;5;61:*.tlz=00;38;5;61:*.txz=00;38;5;61:*.zip=00;38;5;61:*.z=00;38;5;61:*.Z=00;38;5;61:*.dz=00;38;5;61:*.gz=00;38;5;61:*.lz=00;38;5;61:*.xz=00;38;5;61:*.bz2=00;38;5;61:*.bz=00;38;5;61:*.tbz=00;38;5;61:*.tbz2=00;38;5;61:*.tz=00;38;5;61:*.deb=00;38;5;61:*.rpm=00;38;5;61:*.jar=00;38;5;61:*.rar=00;38;5;61:*.ace=00;38;5;61:*.zoo=00;38;5;61:*.cpio=00;38;5;61:*.7z=00;38;5;61:*.rz=00;38;5;61:*.apk=00;38;5;61:*.gem=00;38;5;61:*.jpg=00;38;5;136:*.JPG=00;38;5;136:*.jpeg=00;38;5;136:*.gif=00;38;5;136:*.bmp=00;38;5;136:*.pbm=00;38;5;136:*.pgm=00;38;5;136:*.ppm=00;38;5;136:*.tga=00;38;5;136:*.xbm=00;38;5;136:*.xpm=00;38;5;136:*.tif=00;38;5;136:*.tiff=00;38;5;136:*.png=00;38;5;136:*.PNG=00;38;5;136:*.svg=00;38;5;136:*.svgz=00;38;5;136:*.mng=00;38;5;136:*.pcx=00;38;5;136:*.dl=00;38;5;136:*.xcf=00;38;5;136:*.xwd=00;38;5;136:*.yuv=00;38;5;136:*.cgm=00;38;5;136:*.emf=00;38;5;136:*.eps=00;38;5;136:*.CR2=00;38;5;136:*.ico=00;38;5;136:*.tex=00;38;5;245:*.rdf=00;38;5;245:*.owl=00;38;5;245:*.n3=00;38;5;245:*.ttl=00;38;5;245:*.nt=00;38;5;245:*.torrent=00;38;5;245:*.xml=00;38;5;245:*Makefile=00;38;5;245:*Rakefile=00;38;5;245:*Dockerfile=00;38;5;245:*build.xml=00;38;5;245:*rc=00;38;5;245:*1=00;38;5;245:*.nfo=00;38;5;245:*README=00;38;5;245:*README.txt=00;38;5;245:*readme.txt=00;38;5;245:*.md=00;38;5;245:*README.markdown=00;38;5;245:*.ini=00;38;5;245:*.yml=00;38;5;245:*.cfg=00;38;5;245:*.conf=00;38;5;245:*.h=00;38;5;245:*.hpp=00;38;5;245:*.c=00;38;5;245:*.cpp=00;38;5;245:*.cxx=00;38;5;245:*.cc=00;38;5;245:*.objc=00;38;5;245:*.sqlite=00;38;5;245:*.go=00;38;5;245:*.sql=00;38;5;245:*.csv=00;38;5;245:*.log=00;38;5;240:*.bak=00;38;5;240:*.aux=00;38;5;240:*.lof=00;38;5;240:*.lol=00;38;5;240:*.lot=00;38;5;240:*.out=00;38;5;240:*.toc=00;38;5;240:*.bbl=00;38;5;240:*.blg=00;38;5;240:*~=00;38;5;240:*#=00;38;5;240:*.part=00;38;5;240:*.incomplete=00;38;5;240:*.swp=00;38;5;240:*.tmp=00;38;5;240:*.temp=00;38;5;240:*.o=00;38;5;240:*.pyc=00;38;5;240:*.class=00;38;5;240:*.cache=00;38;5;240:*.aac=00;38;5;166:*.au=00;38;5;166:*.flac=00;38;5;166:*.mid=00;38;5;166:*.midi=00;38;5;166:*.mka=00;38;5;166:*.mp3=00;38;5;166:*.mpc=00;38;5;166:*.ogg=00;38;5;166:*.opus=00;38;5;166:*.ra=00;38;5;166:*.wav=00;38;5;166:*.m4a=00;38;5;166:*.axa=00;38;5;166:*.oga=00;38;5;166:*.spx=00;38;5;166:*.xspf=00;38;5;166:*.mov=00;38;5;166:*.MOV=00;38;5;166:*.mpg=00;38;5;166:*.mpeg=00;38;5;166:*.m2v=00;38;5;166:*.mkv=00;38;5;166:*.ogm=00;38;5;166:*.mp4=00;38;5;166:*.m4v=00;38;5;166:*.mp4v=00;38;5;166:*.vob=00;38;5;166:*.qt=00;38;5;166:*.nuv=00;38;5;166:*.wmv=00;38;5;166:*.asf=00;38;5;166:*.rm=00;38;5;166:*.rmvb=00;38;5;166:*.flc=00;38;5;166:*.avi=00;38;5;166:*.fli=00;38;5;166:*.flv=00;38;5;166:*.gl=00;38;5;166:*.m2ts=00;38;5;166:*.divx=00;38;5;166:*.webm=00;38;5;166:*.axv=00;38;5;166:*.anx=00;38;5;166:*.ogv=00;38;5;166:*.ogx=00;38;5;166:';
export LS_COLORS
```

While single quotes would suppress all expansions, so

```
echo 'eval `dircolors ${dircolorsdb}`'
```

would output

```
eval `dircolors ${dircolorsdb}`
```

How do I insert the correct text ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to insert

```bsh
eval `dircolors $HOME/.dir_colors/dircolors.256dark`
```

in your  `~/.zshrc` as-is just quote it with single quotes:

```bsh
echo 'eval `dircolors $HOME/.dir_colors/dircolors.256dark`' >>~/.zshrc
```

If you need a variable to be expanded, use double quotes and nest it *or* use double quotes and escape `` ` `` (or any combination):

```bsh
echo 'eval `dircolors '"$dircolorsdb"'`' >>~/.zshrc # or
echo "eval \`dircolors $dircolorsdb\`" >>~/.zshrc
```

This won't work as expected in your case because `$HOME` is expanded already when you assign the variable, so – you guessed it – quote at least the special character `$`:

```bsh
dircolorsdb='$HOME/.dir_colors/dircolors.256dark' # or
dircolorsdb='$'HOME/.dir_colors/dircolors.256dark # or
dircolorsdb=\$HOME/.dir_colors/dircolors.256dark
```